# How to prepare the dataset to use mixlogit in stata

Tags: stata

I am planning to use the mixlogit command in stata. This command has a specific requirement of how data should be prepared. An example is given below

```
    choice speed cost group  id

      0      5    3     1    1         
      1      8    4     1    1         
      0      6    3     1    1       
      0      3    2     2    1         
      0      2    2     2    1         
      1      5    4     2    1         
      0      6    4     2    1
```

The background is individual chooses cars based on car characteristics. Choice is a binary variable indicating choice. speed, cost are characteristics. Id indicates person identifier.

I have a dataset like this.

```
    Drug Half_life Price ID
    1      8        10    1
    2      7         6    2
```

where drug is the id of each drug chosen, half_life and price are drug characteristics, and ID is individual identifier.

The problem now is I don't have observations for drugs that each individual did not choose. I only have observations for actual choice. How should I prepare the dataset to make it look like the first one described.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work, unless your data has a more complicated structure (prices vary across people, ID is not sequential):

```
clear

input Drug Half_life Price ID
    1      8        10    1
    2      7         6    2
end

gen choice = 1
xtset Drug ID
tsfill, full
xfill Half_life Price, i(Drug)
replace choice = 0 if missing(choice)
```

This will get you something like:

```
Drug   Half_life   Price   ID   choice  
   1          8      10    1        1  
   1          8      10    2        0  
   2          7       6    1        0  
   2          7       6    2        1
```

Another approach would be to make a dataset of drugs and "cross" it with the users:

```
tempfile drugs

preserve
keep Drug Half_life Price
duplicates drop
save `drugs'
restore

keep Drug ID
rename Drug choice
cross using `drugs'
replace choice=0 if Drug!=choice
replace choice=1 if Drug==choice
```

Comment: I do have a more complicated data structure. First, it's a panel. Second, the price for each drug varies for people.

Comment: If you can't figure out how to modify my code, why don't you add a more realistic data example in your question? Also, give the desired output for that particular data example.

Comment: I am trying to modify the code. Panel is not a issue. Apparently, id not sequential is a problem.

Comment: There are all kinds of assumptions that are needed to give a solution. For instance, how do you you know which price someone is quoted if they did not buy and prices vary across people? What does the time variable looks like? Are panels balanced? If your ids have lots of gaps, it is probably easiest to use something like the second approach.

Comment: I agree. That's why it's hard to give all the details in the question. I am working on it. I will edit the questions when I figure out what are the necessary steps to do it and what assumptions are needed. Thanks for your suggestion.